# Connecting Ruby and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in windows 7 and I installed ruby 1.9.2p180 and MySQL 5.5.15 and mysql gem.
now how can I connect ruby to mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new rails app with mysql instead of the default sqlite by using:

```
rails new APPNAME -d mysql
```

Or the long form:

```
rails new APPNAME --database=mysql
```

You can then take a look at the generated file `config/database.yml` to see the settings used for mysql.  You will need to set up your username, password and database in here.  Don't forget that with mysql, you will need to create the database manually for each environment.

Sample config/database.yml:

```
development:
    adapter: mysql
    encoding: utf8
    reconnect: false
    database: test_database
    pool: 20
    username: root
    password: root
    host: localhost
    socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: When I used 'rails new -d mysql' ruby gave me this error : option should be given after the application name.

Comment: Apologies, you still need to specify your app name.  See my edits, replacing APPNAME with whatever your all is called.

Comment: Excuse me , can you take a small ruby code that connect to MySQL ?

Comment: I have posted the config from one of my mysql apps, it is simply what was generated by the command I posted previously.

Answer (score 0):

Just install mysql2 gem and when you want to create a new project run

```
rails new APPNAME --database=mysql
```